# Is there any way to add label or marker inside layer of a google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new with google map API. I need to place a label inside a google map datalayer. I need to get understand is it possible to write any javascript code to solve this problem?

```
  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: {
        path: resultPath,
        fillColor: resultColor,
        fillOpacity: .2,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        scale: 10
      }
    });
```

from the above code instead of 'map:map' can we use any layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google.maps.Data` layer doesn't receive common overlay objects (marker, polyline, polygon, circle, rectangle). It displays `google.maps.Data.Feature` objects or GeoJSON valid literals.

You could, for example, add a marker to the data layer by doing

```
var geoJsonFeature = {
    type:'Feature',
    geometry:{
      type:'Point',
      coordinates:[e.latLng.lng(), e.latLng.lat()]
    }
}

google.maps.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonFeature);
```

Regarding the styling of your marker, you can set the datalayer style as

```
google.maps.data.setStyle(function(Feature) {

   return {
      icon: {
        path: Feature.getProperty('resultPath'),
        fillColor: Feature.getProperty('resultColor'),
        fillOpacity: .2,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5,
        scale: 10
     }
   };        

});
```

so, for each datalayer `google.maps.data.Feature` you add, if you want markers to have different styles, you should set their path and fillColor beforehand as

```
var geoJsonFeature = {
    type:'Feature',
    properties: {
       path: resultPath,
       fillColor: resultColor
    },
    geometry:{
      type:'Point',
      coordinates:[e.latLng.lng(), e.latLng.lat()]
    }
}
```